# My Google adsense account is verified, then also i'll need to verify my ID after buying play console developer account?

Tags: google-play, admob, ads, adsense, google-play-console

I have a Google Adsense account, I'm using it to show ads on my websites, also I'm using Admob to show ads on my applications. Everything is working fine as I have successfully verified my ID and Address with PIN and receiving money. And now I want to publish my applications on Google Play Store so I visited website to buy console account, it's written that google may ask to verify my identity and if failed money won't be refunded. My question is that after buying it, will google ask me to verify my identity with my photograph and government ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They usually do not try to verify you, but usually it happened when you want to get payment for IAP (in app purchases) inside your apps.

Then they will ask for government ID (I recommend using passport), and will ask you to add a bank account to receive your money, it will take couple of days then they will verify you.

Do not worry it is normal process, the nonrefundable part is the 24$ you pay to open Google Play Developer account.

They may ask you to [verify your phone number](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10841920?hl=en) (it depends on your country, this is not done in all countries)